# How to deploy Amazon Sagemaker Pipeline using Serverless?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I use this code for Serverless deploy

```
from sagemaker.serverless import ServerlessInferenceConfig

serverless_config = ServerlessInferenceConfig(
    memory_size_in_mb = 2048,
    max_concurrency = 5
)
serverless_predictor = sm_model.deploy(serverless_inference_config = serverless_config)
```

TypeError: PipelineModel.deploy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serverless_inference_config'

also sm_model is It consists of a model learned with xgboost and a preprocessing code for deriving prediction results in the model
It's okay to simply distribute it, but in this case, it's very expensive, so how can I distribute it as a serverless one? Even if I look at the official documents, I don't care about the model I learned, but the preprocessing part is very painful because it doesn't learn at all. Can I run the preprocessing code in lambda and send it?

I checked Amazon's official documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PipelineModel currently doesn't have serverless option.
I found a relevant feature request in GitHub forum here:

https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/2891

Please consider adding your comment to +1 to this feature request.

Comment: You can also more simply use the SageMaker Step Decorator for your Pipeline steps, here you are not constrained to any native step availability and can define a Python function with the step decorator: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipelines-step-decorator.html